# How to kill a localhost 3000 from terminal?

Tags: server, localhost

Error message:
Something is already running on port 3000. Probably:
/usr/local/bin/node /Users/cr/my-app/node_modules/react-scripts/scripts/start.js (pid 42585)
in /Users/cr/my-app

Would you like to run the app on another port instead? Y/N

Tryed:

"Control + C" but this is only finishing the task but not the server

Answer (score 0):

To find and terminate an application running on a specific port, you can use the `lsof` command followed by the `kill` command. Here's how you can do it:

1. First, use the `lsof` command to list all processes listening on a specific port. For example, to find processes listening on port 3000, you would use:

   ```
   lsof -i :3000
   ```

   This command will give you a list of processes using port 3000. You'll see various columns in the output; the one labeled `PID` is the process ID.
2. Copy the PID of the process you want to terminate. This is usually found in the second column of the output.
3. Then, use the `kill` command with the PID to terminate the process. For example, here the PID is 12345, you would use:

   ```
   kill -9 12345
   ```

   The `-9` option sends the `SIGKILL` signal to the process, ensuring it is terminated immediately.

Remember, using `kill -9` forces the process to terminate without cleanly shutting down. This should be used cautiously, as it does not allow the application to perform any cleanup operations. If possible, use `kill` without the `-9` option first to allow the process to terminate gracefully.